# ant multiple artifacts of the module are retrieved to the same file

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I am using ant, and I have facing some problems related to multiple artefacts of the module are retrieved to the same file.
Please share the possible way for solving the above issue.

This is my build.xml:

[image: ant configuration]

This is the error:

[image: error page]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the config and error adding them to the question space and not a link to them

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates what you have to do, update the retrieve task's pattern.

I'm purely guessing (because you have not supplied your ivy or settings files) but here's what might work

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
```

This pattern will tell ivy how to name the retrieved files. In Maven repositories it's common to have additional (but optional) javadoc and source jars.