# Multiple artifacts of the module X are retrieved to the same file in Apache Ivy?

Tags: java, build, ant, ivy

I am getting below error when i build with ant :

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/rajeevprasanna/Desktop/Nutch/nutch-release-1.14/build.xml:116: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/rajeevprasanna/Desktop/Nutch/nutch-release-1.14/src/plugin/build.xml:34: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/rajeevprasanna/Desktop/Nutch/nutch-release-1.14/src/plugin/build-plugin.xml:230: impossible to ivy retrieve: java.lang.RuntimeException: problem during retrieve of org.apache.nutch#lib-selenium: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple artifacts of the module commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 are retrieved to the same file! Update the retrieve pattern  to fix this error.
    at org.apache.ivy.core.retrieve.RetrieveEngine.retrieve(RetrieveEngine.java:206)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.retrieve(Ivy.java:540)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve.doExecute(IvyRetrieve.java:59)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I have configuration set as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283757/how-do-i-solve-multiple-artifacts-of-the-module-x-are-retrieved-to-the-same-file) :

```
<target name="resolve-default" depends="clean-default-lib" description="--> resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:resolve file="${ivy.file}" conf="default" log="download-only"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.lib.dir}/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" symlink="false" log="quiet"/>
    <antcall target="copy-libs"/>
  </target>

  <target name="resolve-test" depends="clean-test-lib, init" description="--> resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:resolve file="${ivy.file}" conf="test" log="download-only"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${test.build.lib.dir}/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" symlink="false" log="quiet"/>
    <antcall target="copy-libs"/>
  </target>
```

commons-codec dependency is like below in ivy.xml :

```
<dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.10" conf="*->default" />
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need all the confs mapped to your `default` ?

Comment: Rajeev, could you solve the issue? I am stuck on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add the configuration name (`conf`) to the retrieve pattern, so that dependencies belongingn to multiple configurations (`default` and `test`, ...) map to different directories:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" symlink="false" log="quiet"/>
```